# How to model a self-referencing has_many relationship in ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I want to model a `has_many` children relationship in Ecto. I am wondering if I need a separate table to store this relationship. Or is it enough to store the relationship between a todo and its parent. I know that's only one way. But I wonder if it's sufficient. Creating a whole other table for relationships seems to duplicate what we already know ( a todos parent ). I can understand if that's advisable though.

```
  schema "todos" do
    ...
    # this works
    has_one(:parent, __MODULE__, foreign_key: :parent_todo_id)
    # this does not
    has_many(:children, __MODULE__)
  end
```

Migration:

```
create table("todos", primary_key: false) do
  add :parent_todo_id, references(:todos, type: :uuid), null: true   
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't *need* a separate table: you can define a self-referential relationship in `Ecto`.  There may be pros/cons to this approach, but that's a different question (and questions of preference may not be appropriate for SO).

Here's another example of a nested structure modeling menu items, where each item may have children:

```
defmodule Menuitem do

  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "menus_items" do
    field(:parent_id, :integer)
    field(:order, :integer)
    field(:label, :string)
    
    belongs_to(:parent, Menuitem, foreign_key: :id, references: :menu_item_parent, define_field: false)
    has_many(:children, Menuitem, foreign_key: :parent_id, references: :id)
  end
end
```